# What is a right way to render repeated-background in libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, libgdx

```
public render(){
...
        while (y < Height){
            while(x < Width){
            batch.draw(bg,x,y,bg.getWidth()/ratio,bg.getHeight()/ratio);    
            x += bg.getWidth()/ratio;
            }
            y += bg.getHeight()/ratio;
            x = 0;
        }

...
}
```

I have a pattern texture(bg) which will repeat to make a repeated background, so i make it repeated in render function (code above). At first it works very well, but when the ratio get bigger (so the sprite get smaller to fit the background), it become very laggy. Can you tell me a right way to make repeated background like above code without affect performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it gets laggy because you are drawing hundreds of quads to the screen, and if there are too many, it will become a CPU bottleneck and reduce frame rate. But the other answer might actually be the reason: if you are shrinking a texture significantly without using mip mapping, it will really eat up GPU time.

Since this is just a repeating texture, you only need to draw one quad for the whole screen. First, when you load the texture, make sure it repeats:

```
bg.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat); 
//call this only one time, after you instantiate the Texture
```

Then you can draw a single quad to the screen and set the UV's of the vertices big enough for the number of times you want it to tile.

```
// bottom left corner...wherever you want to put it.
float bottomY = 0; 
float leftX = 0;

//width and height of background. This is just an example. By the way, Java 
//convention is for all variable names to start with a lower-case letter, 
//to avoid confusion.
float width = screenWidth;
float height= screenHeight;

//I'm using RATIO like you are, which I think is the reciprocal of how much 
//you want to scale the texture up. By the way, it is convention to make  
//constant variable (static final primitives in Java) names be in all caps.

float uRight = width * RATIO / bg.getWidth();
float vTop= height * RATIO / bg.getHeight();

batch.draw(bg, leftX, bottomY, width, height, 0, 0, uRight, vTop);
```

Comment: Can you explain what is Quads ?

Comment: Each sprite you draw has two triangles in it that form a quadrilateral (quad). Basically, every sprite has four unique vertices that must be transferred to the GPU when you call `batch.end()`, which takes up CPU cycles. You can draw hundreds of quads per frame and maintain 60fps on a typical smart phone. But if you get into the thousands, it will become a CPU bottleneck on most mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be causing the lag. The biggest one is the fact that your background image is probably a large resolution that you are drawing many times just at a smaller width and height. I would say look into mipmaps and take a look at this tutorial http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403